# How to resolve java.io.FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, android, jsoup, last.fm

I'm trying retrieve artists photos for all music using the last.fm api
but I got `java.io.FileNotFoundException` and I don't know why.

Here is my code

```
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        Bitmap bmp;
        try {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(mArtisName).ignoreContentType(true).ignoreHttpErrors(true);
            Connection.Response resp = connection.execute();
            Document document;
            if (resp.statusCode() ==200) {
                document = connection.parser(Parser.xmlParser()).post();
                mArtisName = document.select("image[size=extralarge]").text();
            }
            bmp = cache.get(Artis);
            if (bmp==null) {
                URL url = new URL(mArtisName);
                URLConnection update = url.openConnection();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(update.getInputStream());
                cache.put(Artis, bmp);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            bmp = defaultBitmap;
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

logcat

```
12-12 17:47:45.739    5331-5356/com.karyaanaknegeri.musikq W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/751c067c9cb6469b9d6d2e33e1791edc.png http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/be563302f6574b3c800b2308970777b6.png http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/15fe26485bc54344bb43d7d05705c46d.png http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/5d54245519f74844806c7918545c6e88.png http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/37696a0d07f849f5bdd34cac656a218e.png http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/3a66a1890a9b4c9d8bf88a8c6d88868d.png
12-12 17:47:45.739    5331-5356/com.karyaanaknegeri.musikq W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:206)
```

Comment: you are requesting several files at once:

http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/751c067c9cb6469b9d6d2e33e1791edc.png
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/be563302f6574b3c800b2308970777b6.png
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/15fe26485bc54344bb43d7d05705c46d.png
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/5d54245519f74844806c7918545c6e88.png
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/37696a0d07f849f5bdd34cac656a218e.png
http://img2-ak.lst.fm/i/u/300x300/3a66a1890a9b4c9d8bf88a8c6d88868d.png
is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are requesting doesn't exist. In fact, your code may hit a 404 error. The URL class indicates this type of error with a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

On the other hand, make sure that the CSS selector `image[size=extralarge]` returns **exactly** one image. Be aware also that the following line will return the **cumulative text of all elements** selected.

```
document.select("image[size=extralarge]").text()
```